# Has changed the way Vertx eventBus multithreading is handled between Quarkus 1.13.7 and Quarkus 2.0.0?

Tags: java, vert.x, quarkus, vertx-eventbus

I'm not really sure if it is a bug of some kind or just a missing config by my side, but I'm getting a different behaviour in the way that the Vertx eventBus assigns the threads to the "@ConsumeEvent" methods.

In the Quarkus version 1.13.7.FINAL and olders, it looks that Vertx binds an eventloop thread to each consumer method, if the pool have enough threads. But in Quarkus 2.0.0 every message is handled by one or two threads, making the execution virtually synchronous. And this behaviour is the same in VM or native mode.

I made a silly project to illustrate this: https://github.com/AngelPerz/test-vertx-q2

In this project, when a call to the **localhost:8080/test** is received, it sends some messages via eventBus to a 3 consumers with .publish() method, simulates some work on each with a simple wait, and sends the completion to a final collector via eventBus too.

With this scenario in **Quarkus 1.13.7.FINAL** the same application executes everything concurrently:

```
2021-07-04 14:18:44,597 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) code-with-quarkus 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT native (powered by Quarkus 1.13.7.Final) started in 0.008s. Listening on: http://0.0.0.0:8080
2021-07-04 14:18:44,598 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Profile prod activated. 
2021-07-04 14:18:44,598 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: [cdi, mutiny, resteasy, smallrye-context-propagation, vertx]
2021-07-04 14:18:50,082 INFO  [org.acm.con.TestLauncher] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-17) Starting test with [5] workUnits
2021-07-04 14:18:50,082 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerC] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-16) ConsumerC :: starting workUnit [0]
2021-07-04 14:18:50,082 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerB] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-14) ConsumerB :: starting workUnit [0]
2021-07-04 14:18:50,082 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerA] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-18) ConsumerA :: starting workUnit [0]
2021-07-04 14:18:50,233 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerC] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-16) ConsumerC :: finished workUnit [0]
2021-07-04 14:18:50,233 INFO  [org.acm.con.TestWorkCollector] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-15) WorkCollector :: received finish work [ConsumerC, 0]
2021-07-04 14:18:50,233 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerB] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-14) ConsumerB :: finished workUnit [0]
2021-07-04 14:18:50,233 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerA] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-18) ConsumerA :: finished workUnit [0]
2021-07-04 14:18:50,233 INFO  [org.acm.con.TestWorkCollector] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-15) WorkCollector :: received finish work [ConsumerB, 0]
2021-07-04 14:18:50,233 INFO  [org.acm.con.TestWorkCollector] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-15) WorkCollector :: received finish work [ConsumerA, 0]
2021-07-04 14:18:50,233 INFO  [org.acm.con.TestWorkCollector] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-15) WorkCollector :: all works completed by consumers for workUnit [0]
2021-07-04 14:18:50,283 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerC] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-16) ConsumerC :: starting workUnit [1]
2021-07-04 14:18:50,283 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerB] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-14) ConsumerB :: starting workUnit [1]
2021-07-04 14:18:50,283 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerA] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-18) ConsumerA :: starting workUnit [1]
2021-07-04 14:18:50,435 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerC] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-16) ConsumerC :: finished workUnit [1]
2021-07-04 14:18:50,435 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerA] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-18) ConsumerA :: finished workUnit [1]
2021-07-04 14:18:50,435 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerB] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-14) ConsumerB :: finished workUnit [1]
2021-07-04 14:18:50,435 INFO  [org.acm.con.TestWorkCollector] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-15) WorkCollector :: received finish work [ConsumerC, 1]
2021-07-04 14:18:50,435 INFO  [org.acm.con.TestWorkCollector] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-15) WorkCollector :: received finish work [ConsumerA, 1]
2021-07-04 14:18:50,435 INFO  [org.acm.con.TestWorkCollector] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-15) WorkCollector :: received finish work [ConsumerB, 1]
2021-07-04 14:18:50,435 INFO  [org.acm.con.TestWorkCollector] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-15) WorkCollector :: all works completed by consumers for workUnit [1]
2021-07-04 14:18:50,483 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerC] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-16) ConsumerC :: starting workUnit [2]
2021-07-04 14:18:50,483 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerB] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-14) ConsumerB :: starting workUnit [2]
2021-07-04 14:18:50,483 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerA] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-18) ConsumerA :: starting workUnit [2]
2021-07-04 14:18:50,633 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerC] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-16) ConsumerC :: finished workUnit [2]
2021-07-04 14:18:50,634 INFO  [org.acm.con.TestWorkCollector] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-15) WorkCollector :: received finish work [ConsumerC, 2]
2021-07-04 14:18:50,634 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerB] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-14) ConsumerB :: finished workUnit [2]
2021-07-04 14:18:50,634 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerA] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-18) ConsumerA :: finished workUnit [2]
2021-07-04 14:18:50,634 INFO  [org.acm.con.TestWorkCollector] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-15) WorkCollector :: received finish work [ConsumerB, 2]
2021-07-04 14:18:50,634 INFO  [org.acm.con.TestWorkCollector] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-15) WorkCollector :: received finish work [ConsumerA, 2]
2021-07-04 14:18:50,634 INFO  [org.acm.con.TestWorkCollector] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-15) WorkCollector :: all works completed by consumers for workUnit [2]
2021-07-04 14:18:50,684 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerA] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-18) ConsumerA :: starting workUnit [3]
2021-07-04 14:18:50,684 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerB] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-14) ConsumerB :: starting workUnit [3]
2021-07-04 14:18:50,684 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerC] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-16) ConsumerC :: starting workUnit [3]
2021-07-04 14:18:50,835 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerC] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-16) ConsumerC :: finished workUnit [3]
2021-07-04 14:18:50,836 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerB] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-14) ConsumerB :: finished workUnit [3]
2021-07-04 14:18:50,836 INFO  [org.acm.con.TestWorkCollector] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-15) WorkCollector :: received finish work [ConsumerC, 3]
2021-07-04 14:18:50,836 INFO  [org.acm.con.TestWorkCollector] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-15) WorkCollector :: received finish work [ConsumerB, 3]
2021-07-04 14:18:50,836 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerA] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-18) ConsumerA :: finished workUnit [3]
2021-07-04 14:18:50,837 INFO  [org.acm.con.TestWorkCollector] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-15) WorkCollector :: received finish work [ConsumerA, 3]
2021-07-04 14:18:50,837 INFO  [org.acm.con.TestWorkCollector] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-15) WorkCollector :: all works completed by consumers for workUnit [3]
2021-07-04 14:18:50,884 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerB] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-14) ConsumerB :: starting workUnit [4]
2021-07-04 14:18:50,884 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerA] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-18) ConsumerA :: starting workUnit [4]
2021-07-04 14:18:50,884 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerC] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-16) ConsumerC :: starting workUnit [4]
2021-07-04 14:18:51,035 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerC] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-16) ConsumerC :: finished workUnit [4]
2021-07-04 14:18:51,035 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerA] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-18) ConsumerA :: finished workUnit [4]
2021-07-04 14:18:51,035 INFO  [org.acm.con.TestWorkCollector] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-15) WorkCollector :: received finish work [ConsumerC, 4]
2021-07-04 14:18:51,035 INFO  [org.acm.con.TestWorkCollector] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-15) WorkCollector :: received finish work [ConsumerA, 4]
2021-07-04 14:18:51,035 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerB] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-14) ConsumerB :: finished workUnit [4]
2021-07-04 14:18:51,037 INFO  [org.acm.con.TestWorkCollector] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-15) WorkCollector :: received finish work [ConsumerB, 4]
2021-07-04 14:18:51,037 INFO  [org.acm.con.TestWorkCollector] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-15) WorkCollector :: all works completed by consumers for workUnit [4]
```

As we can see there are 5 different threads executing the test, but running the same code in **Quarkus 2.0.0.FINAL** there are only one thread executing everything:

```
2021-07-04 13:27:54,523 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) code-with-quarkus 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT native (powered by Quarkus 2.0.0.Final) started in 0.007s. Listening on: http://0.0.0.0:8080
2021-07-04 13:27:54,524 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Profile prod activated. 
2021-07-04 13:27:54,524 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: [cdi, resteasy, smallrye-context-propagation, vertx]
2021-07-04 13:28:03,630 INFO  [org.acm.con.TestLauncher] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) Starting test with [5] workUnits
2021-07-04 13:28:04,632 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerB] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) ConsumerB :: starting workUnit [0]
2021-07-04 13:28:04,784 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerB] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) ConsumerB :: finished workUnit [0]
2021-07-04 13:28:04,784 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerC] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) ConsumerC :: starting workUnit [0]
2021-07-04 13:28:04,940 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerC] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) ConsumerC :: finished workUnit [0]
2021-07-04 13:28:04,940 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerA] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) ConsumerA :: starting workUnit [0]
2021-07-04 13:28:05,091 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerA] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) ConsumerA :: finished workUnit [0]
2021-07-04 13:28:05,091 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerB] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) ConsumerB :: starting workUnit [1]
2021-07-04 13:28:05,242 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerB] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) ConsumerB :: finished workUnit [1]
2021-07-04 13:28:05,242 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerC] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) ConsumerC :: starting workUnit [1]
2021-07-04 13:28:05,395 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerC] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) ConsumerC :: finished workUnit [1]
2021-07-04 13:28:05,395 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerA] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) ConsumerA :: starting workUnit [1]
2021-07-04 13:28:05,548 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerA] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) ConsumerA :: finished workUnit [1]
2021-07-04 13:28:05,549 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerB] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) ConsumerB :: starting workUnit [2]
2021-07-04 13:28:05,702 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerB] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) ConsumerB :: finished workUnit [2]
2021-07-04 13:28:05,702 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerC] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) ConsumerC :: starting workUnit [2]
2021-07-04 13:28:05,854 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerC] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) ConsumerC :: finished workUnit [2]
2021-07-04 13:28:05,854 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerA] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) ConsumerA :: starting workUnit [2]
2021-07-04 13:28:06,005 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerA] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) ConsumerA :: finished workUnit [2]
2021-07-04 13:28:06,006 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerB] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) ConsumerB :: starting workUnit [3]
2021-07-04 13:28:06,158 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerB] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) ConsumerB :: finished workUnit [3]
2021-07-04 13:28:06,158 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerC] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) ConsumerC :: starting workUnit [3]
2021-07-04 13:28:06,310 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerC] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) ConsumerC :: finished workUnit [3]
2021-07-04 13:28:06,310 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerA] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) ConsumerA :: starting workUnit [3]
2021-07-04 13:28:06,461 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerA] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) ConsumerA :: finished workUnit [3]
2021-07-04 13:28:06,461 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerB] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) ConsumerB :: starting workUnit [4]
2021-07-04 13:28:06,611 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerB] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) ConsumerB :: finished workUnit [4]
2021-07-04 13:28:06,611 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerC] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) ConsumerC :: starting workUnit [4]
2021-07-04 13:28:06,761 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerC] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) ConsumerC :: finished workUnit [4]
2021-07-04 13:28:06,762 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerA] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) ConsumerA :: starting workUnit [4]
2021-07-04 13:28:06,915 INFO  [org.acm.con.ConsumerA] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) ConsumerA :: finished workUnit [4]
2021-07-04 13:28:06,915 INFO  [org.acm.con.TestWorkCollector] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) WorkCollector :: received finish work [ConsumerB, 0]
2021-07-04 13:28:06,915 INFO  [org.acm.con.TestWorkCollector] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) WorkCollector :: received finish work [ConsumerC, 0]
2021-07-04 13:28:06,916 INFO  [org.acm.con.TestWorkCollector] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) WorkCollector :: received finish work [ConsumerA, 0]
2021-07-04 13:28:06,916 INFO  [org.acm.con.TestWorkCollector] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) WorkCollector :: all works completed by consumers for workUnit [0]
2021-07-04 13:28:06,916 INFO  [org.acm.con.TestWorkCollector] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) WorkCollector :: received finish work [ConsumerB, 1]
2021-07-04 13:28:06,916 INFO  [org.acm.con.TestWorkCollector] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) WorkCollector :: received finish work [ConsumerC, 1]
2021-07-04 13:28:06,916 INFO  [org.acm.con.TestWorkCollector] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) WorkCollector :: received finish work [ConsumerA, 1]
2021-07-04 13:28:06,916 INFO  [org.acm.con.TestWorkCollector] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) WorkCollector :: all works completed by consumers for workUnit [1]
2021-07-04 13:28:06,916 INFO  [org.acm.con.TestWorkCollector] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) WorkCollector :: received finish work [ConsumerB, 2]
2021-07-04 13:28:06,916 INFO  [org.acm.con.TestWorkCollector] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) WorkCollector :: received finish work [ConsumerC, 2]
2021-07-04 13:28:06,916 INFO  [org.acm.con.TestWorkCollector] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) WorkCollector :: received finish work [ConsumerA, 2]
2021-07-04 13:28:06,916 INFO  [org.acm.con.TestWorkCollector] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) WorkCollector :: all works completed by consumers for workUnit [2]
2021-07-04 13:28:06,916 INFO  [org.acm.con.TestWorkCollector] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) WorkCollector :: received finish work [ConsumerB, 3]
2021-07-04 13:28:06,916 INFO  [org.acm.con.TestWorkCollector] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) WorkCollector :: received finish work [ConsumerC, 3]
2021-07-04 13:28:06,916 INFO  [org.acm.con.TestWorkCollector] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) WorkCollector :: received finish work [ConsumerA, 3]
2021-07-04 13:28:06,916 INFO  [org.acm.con.TestWorkCollector] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) WorkCollector :: all works completed by consumers for workUnit [3]
2021-07-04 13:28:06,916 INFO  [org.acm.con.TestWorkCollector] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) WorkCollector :: received finish work [ConsumerB, 4]
2021-07-04 13:28:06,916 INFO  [org.acm.con.TestWorkCollector] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) WorkCollector :: received finish work [ConsumerC, 4]
2021-07-04 13:28:06,916 INFO  [org.acm.con.TestWorkCollector] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) WorkCollector :: received finish work [ConsumerA, 4]
2021-07-04 13:28:06,916 INFO  [org.acm.con.TestWorkCollector] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) WorkCollector :: all works completed by consumers for workUnit [4]
```

The time difference between executions are 955ms in 1.13.7.FINAL and 2592ms in 2.0.0.FINAL; and if it can be relevant, was tested with GraalVM 21.0.0.2 java11

Comment: This is due to https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/pull/3431. I've started a conversation as I believe it introduces some issues (like yours).

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Clement and for the conversation to try to fix it, but looking the commits I can't understand how changes made a year ago can cause this issue now. Can you please give me an explanation to understand what is happening? And if I can help in any way let me know.

Comment: So, it's a bug. I was able to fix it in Quarkus. I will push a pull request tomorrow (my fix needs polishing).

Comment: PR opened: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/18436

Comment: Thank you @Clement for the fix and your feedback

Comment: The PR has been merged.

Answer (score 0):

Finally it was a bug and the fix has been included in the Quarkus release 2.0.2.Final

Answer (score 0):

In older versions of Quarkus try to deploy the verticle in the verticle deployer in a loop with as many threads you need.

Remember to check if the verticle performs blocking tasks and configure it properly.